# Why was Reptil a main character on The Super Hero Squad Show?

Tags: marvel

*The Super Hero Squad Show* was a self-aware parody of Marvel comics aimed at children that aired from 2009 to 2011. On a personal note, it helped establish my love of Marvel and its characters. One of the main members of the titular team was Reptil, a relatively obscure character from the comics who can transform part of his body into part of a dinosaur's body. Given his first appearance in the comics was around the time when *The Super Hero Squad Show* was being developed, was he created with the intent of appearing in the show? If not, why was such an obscure character chosen to fight alongside the likes of icons such as Iron Man, Hulk, and Wolverine?

Comment: "who can transform part of his body into part of a dinosaur's body" — which part?!?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Any part, if memory serves. And at one point there was a smutty joke about it, so you're not the first to go there.

Comment: @DonatelloSwansino - Probably because they wanted to add in some edgy teens, but not have the hassle of licensing existing characters more than they have to

Comment: @PaulD.Waite He can transform his big toe into a dinosaur's gall bladder. Not the most ideal power, but what are you gonna do?

Comment: @DonatelloSwansino It's the last thing they'll expect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several wiki sites that claim Reptil was created for the TV show, but I can't actually find a valid reference for that.

In terms of first publication, that appears to vary by source, probably not helped by the fact that Reptil's first main universe appearance was [Avengers: The Initiative Featuring Reptil (March 2009)](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/23847/avengers_the_initiative_featuring_reptil_2009_1) and his first Super Hero Squad Appearance was in the tie-in comic [Super Hero Squad: Hero Up! (also March 2009)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Super_Hero_Squad:_Hero_Up!_Vol_1_1).

Reptil appeared in the actual Super Hero Squad TV show a few months later in the episode [To Err is Superhuman (first aired in October 2009)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Super_Hero_Squad_Show_episodes).

The first Marver Super Hero Squad Reptil figurine  (the toy line that spawned the cartoon) came out with [wave 18 in January 2010](https://hasbroheroes.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Superhero_Squad).

Whatever medium Reptil was first created for, Marvel appear to have been banking on him from the start, this appears to be backed up in a [media article from March 2009](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.cbr.com/avengers-the-initiative-featuring-reptil-1/amp/) that quoted marvel as billing Reptil as "the next big thing".

So to sum up, Marvel had a new character which they believed would be a huge hit and just threw him into everything at more or less the same time.

Comment: I like the CBR media article a lot. I honestly think that should be at the very start of your answer (complete with a quote) and then everything else below that.

Comment: You might want to include this article also since it has direct quotes from a Marvel writer; https://www.gamesradar.com/uk/marvel-comics-bills-reptil-as-its-next-biggest-hero/